# datetime dateutil calculation returns strange format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in string format. I'd like to calculate another date that is 1 year earlier. I tried to format the returned result but didn't get the expected format.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import datetime
latest = '2021-03-01'
date_minus_1y = datetime.datetime.strptime(latest, "%Y-%m-%d") - (dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=12))
date_minus_1y.strftime("%Y-%m%-%d")
```

I received result `'2020-03%d'` but I want `2020-03-01`.

Thank you

Comment: Note : [why "import *" is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/10197418). dateutil docs are a bad example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_minus_1y.strftime("%Y-%m%-%d")
```

should be

```
date_minus_1y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```